# Stop a smart contract to be created in Ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, contract-development

I have a smart contract with some constructor code that has a `throw` statement in there, if certain conditions are satisfied.

But even with that, seems like contract is deployed and I get a transaction receipt and a contract address back, though when I look at the generated contract, it does not have all the properties and data.

Is there a way to stop the "Contract Deploy" transaction to be committed if the constructor code throws?

Here is the sample smart contract code I got:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract MyCoin {

    function MyCoin(address _finalDestination, uint _contractGracePeriod, address _parentContract) 
    {
        if(_parentContract == address(0))
        {
            hupCount = 0; 
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post a txid? of course there will be txid, but contract won't be generated

Comment: Contract creation does indeed fail if it reverts in the constructor. It does not construct the contract. You can verify it with `eth.getCode`. However, just like any other OOG transaction, you do still get a receipt.

Comment: @LibertyLocked is correct here. If the constructor fails, your contract will not be created but you will still see a transaction receipt. I would also suggested to use `require()` here instead of `throw` conditions as it is deprecated as of last updates. http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/control-structures.html?highlight=require#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions

Comment: @LibertyLocked: you should put your comment into an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Revert / OOG in constructor

If there is a REVERT or OOG (out-of-gas) in constructors, the transaction will not construct the contract. However you do still get a **transaction receipt** for the contract creation transaction you send (to address `0x00`), and gas is paid.

This of course will also increment the `nonce` (transaction count) of the deployer. The next you deploy another contract the address of the contract will not be the same.

Consider the following example.

```
pragma solidity 0.4.21;

contract ConstructorTest {
    function ConstructorTest(address parent) public {
        assert(parent != 0);
    }
}
```

Creating this contract with `0` as `parent` will cause the transaction to OOG, because `assert` fails. In that case, all the gas you paid for the transaction will be consumed, paid to the miner of the block.

Similar case if you replace `assert` with `require`. It causes a `REVERT`, so you get remaining gas back.

---

## Checking if contract has been deployed

Simply checking if you get the tx receipt is not enough, because in case of OOG or revert you still get the receipt.

I can think of 2 ways to check if contract has been successfully deployed.

- Read your contract address, `contractAddress`, off the receipt with `eth.getTransactionReceipt`. Then use `eth.getCode` to check if the code is `0x`
- Check the `status` of the transaction receipt. If it's `0` then the tx is mined but failed.